# Need to navigate to a folder in command prompt

Tags: windows, cmd

My command prompt starts in C:\Users\ (Name) and I need it to be in a different folder, how can I do this using the command prompt itself?

Answer (score 101):

Navigate to the folder in Windows Explorer, highlight the complete folder path in the top pane and type "cmd" - voila!

Answer (score 62):

I prefer to use

```
pushd d:\windows\movie
```

because it requires no switches yet the working directory will change to the correct drive and path in one step.

Added plus:

- also works with UNC paths if an unused drive letter is available for automatic drive mapping,
- easy to go back to the previous working directory: just enter `popd`.

Answer (score 14):

In MS-DOS `COMMAND.COM` shell, you have to use:

```
d:

cd \windows\movie
```

---

If by chance you actually meant "Windows command prompt" (which is not MS-DOS and not DOS at all), then you can use `cd /d d:\windows\movie`.

Comment: it doesnot work !! telling as syntax incorrect

Answer (score 9):

Just use the change directory (cd) command.

```
cd d:\windows\movie
```

Answer (score 7):

To access another drive, type the drive's letter, followed by ":".

```
D:
```

Then enter:

```
cd d:\windows\movie
```

Comment: Is the `d:\` in the second entry necessary though?

Answer (score 1):

When I open a "DOS" command prompt, I use a batch file which sets all of the options I need and adds my old-time dos utilities to the path too.

```
@set path=%path%;c:\utils
@doskey cd=cd/d $*
@cd \wip
@cmd.exe
```

The doskey line sets the CD command so that it will do both drive and folder simultaneously. If this doesn't work, it is possibly because of the version of windows that you're running.