# how to run textcleaner imagemagick script from git bash

Tags: image

I installed Git Bash on Windows system. Now I want to run textcleaner Imagemagick script from it. Which package do I need to download to run textcleaner script and how to set the path for that  script. Please help.

Comment: found this fancy old comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33411898/how-to-use-freds-imagemagick-textcleaner-script, This should help :)

Comment: this is not working.

Comment: what did you try? And is ur textcleaner in the right directory?

Comment: and if you are on your command line, what happens if you write ```bash```

Comment: From where I can download textcleaner script and where I should keep to run it.

Comment: http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/textcleaner/index.php

Comment: See the Pointers for Use at http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/index.php. See also on that page, the bullet items for Windows with Cygwin and Windows 10 Unix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steps to make textcleaner work:

1. open git bash.
2. navigate to the directory of your wish. This way you avoid writing long paths to your images and stuff (see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/22509024/8340945)
3. insert the downloaded script in this directory.
4. (as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33411898/how-to-use-freds-imagemagick-textcleaner-script))

   - chmod +x textcleaner
   - ./textcleaner ... arguments ..